# Customising AVPlayerViewController progress bar

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

I am working on `AVPlayerViewController` and using it I am playing HLS video. Is it possible to add some dots at different time interval(e.g. at 10 , 20 etc minutes yellow dots) on progress bar in tvOS?

Or is their any other approach using which I can achieve this.

Comment: Share what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the answer after going through apple developer blog and various other blogs

We can use setInterstitialTimeRanges method to set InterstitialTimeRanges property of AVPlayerItem

[self.playerItem setInterstitialTimeRanges:self.timeRangeArray];

where self.timeRangeArray is an array of AVInterstitialTimeRange objects which will be shown on progress bar of AVPlayerViewController.

Comment: Hey I am struggling with that too. My ads are stitched in the stream so if content length was 50 minutes after adding 10 minutes of ads the length will be 60 minutes. But when I add these ranges they don't appear on proper places do you have any idea ?